# Transform from rosbuild package to catkin package

Tags: ros, catkin, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My OS is ubuntu12.10 and ros groovy.

I want to transform pr2_controllers_msgs package.

```
command:catkinize pr2_controllers_msgs 1.0.0
```

error message:

```
ira@ira:~/code/ros_groovy/src$ catkinize pr2_controllers_msgs 1.0.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/catkinize", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('catkinize==0.1', 'catkinize')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 499, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 1239, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkinize-0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/catkinize", line 61, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkinize-0.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/catkinize", line 56, in main
    changeset = catkinize_stack(path, version)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/catkinize-0.1-py2.7.egg/catkinize/main.py", line 79, in catkinize_stack
    path)
ValueError: Path is not a rosbuild stack, missing stack.xml at pr2_controllers_msgs
ira@ira:~/code/ros_groovy/src$
```

How to solve it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/72631/transform-from-rosbuild-package-to-catkin-package/) by [li-an](https://answers.ros.org/users/2411/li-an/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2013-08-13

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2013-08-13**:
You might want to consider to use Hydro since pr2_controllers_msgs has already been catkinized for that ROS version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a guide to converting rosbuild to catkin packages here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/catkin/migrating_from_rosbuild

However I do not recommend you do so for this package.  It's already been done for the hydro version. If you're using catkin the Hydro version will probably provide you with more packages already catkinized as well.  You can also attempt to use the hydro version inside groovy but your effectiveness will vary.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2013-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2